# java JButton setIcon won't work

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a 2D array of JButtons. I also have an image which is in the same directory as the class file. This image is called "Ship.bmp". The method below won't set this image to the button, why?

```
public void placeShip(int x, int y) {
    buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("Ship.bmp");
    if (imgURL != null) {
        icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: Ship.bmp");
        icon = null;
    }
    System.out.println(imgURL);
    buttons[x+1][y+1].setIcon(icon);
}
```

P.S. I'm NOT using eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: was there any error thrown ?

Comment: how do you know that `x+1` and `y+1` doesn't go out of bound? If they are okay, then how do you know that the button size will be sufficient to contain the icon (i.e. the sizes are coherent)

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: I can't tell for sure without seeing your other code, but I bet you need to repaint after this method is called.

Comment: From the [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) tutorial, *"Swing provides a particularly useful implementation of the Icon interface: ImageIcon, which paints an icon from a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image."*. From memory, bmp's aren't supported, you'd have to use ImageIO api instead

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info :) x+1 and y+1 doesn't go out of border, that's for sure. Code runs and no errors are thrown. The code simply call this method with x = 1, y = 1, and array itself is 12 x 12. I'm not sure if the sizes are coherent, can I resize the image somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Java Icon tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) only GIF, JPEG and PNG image formats are supported by ImageIcon. You might need to change the format of the image, or use the ImageIO class to load the imgae first instead.